# Authentication with Remember me. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a user dashboard where the user can check a checkbox to enable a single sign in. To achieve this I am trying to use user authentication with remember me. Below is my controller code for the same.

```
$userdata = array( 'username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password') );

    $rememberMe = false;

    if(Input::has('remember_me')) {
       $rememberMe = true;
    }

    if (Auth::attempt($userdata, $rememberMe)) {

        echo "Success!";

    } else {        

        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors("Invalid credentials. Try again");

    }
```

When i run this controller, remember_token is created but it is not adding a cookie. What could be the possible error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo, check out your session config...
if you get thrown back at login page, it's probably misconfigured site URL.

I've spent HOURS AND HOURS dicking around with this.

in your app>config>session.php look for domain => '';